# How to schedule task which will execute every 1st day of month and update a value in Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database in my android app.I have details of every person along with a field `feepaidforcurrentmonth` boolean.I have 2 fragments feespaid and feenotpaid. When fee is paid for current month `feepaidforcurrentmonth` becomes true and gets updated in firebase database and the member is added to the list of feespaid fragment from feenotpaid.

My question is how do I schedule task in firebase/or in my app to set the value of field `feepaidforcurrentmonth` false every first day of month?How do I update it in firebase database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a task you should do in the backend rather than the frontend (your app).

You could use an external self written and hosted backend, e.g. python that's triggered by a cron tab.

[Here's a blog post from firebase about the topic](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html). They are using Google App Engine to trigger based on time / date.